# Find missing term in arithmetic progression -

Tags: java, math, io

So I'm working on this programming challenge online where I'm supposed to write a program that finds the missing term in an arithmetic progression. I solved the problem in two ways: one that used summing all the given terms of the progression and then subtracting that from the sum of  the actual progression. My other solution was based on finding the difference of the progression, and then using that difference in a for loop to find the missing term. While my first solution successfully passes all test cases, my second solution fails two out of the 7 test cases. The challenge doesn't allow anyone to see their test cases so I had no idea what was wrong. Can anyone think of cases where my second solution fails to find the missing term of an arithmetic progression? Code for my second solution is below.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        String[] numbers = br.readLine().split(" ");
        Vector<Integer> ap = new Vector<Integer>();
        for (String str: numbers){
            ap.add(Integer.parseInt(str));
        }
        int first = ap.get(0);
        int last = ap.get(ap.size()-1);
        int incr = (last-first)/num;
        for(int i = first; i<=last; i+= incr){
            if(!ap.contains(i)){
                System.out.println(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Input Format The first line contains an Integer N, which is the number of terms which will be provided as input. This is followed by N consecutive Integers, with a space between each pair of integers. All of these are on one line, and they are in AP (other than the point where an integer is missing).

Comment: Are there `num` numbers in the input?  Or `num` numbers in the arithmetic sequence?  Shouldn't those differ by one?

Comment: There are `num` numbers in the input yes. And yes, they do differ by one.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MissingAp 
{
public static void main(String args[]){

    int arr[] ={10,8,4,2,0,-2,-4,-6,-8,-10,-12};
    int difference[]=new int[arr.length-1];
    int missingTerm;

    for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++){
        difference[i-1] = arr[i]-arr[i-1];  
    }
    for(int j =0;j<arr.length-1;j++){

        if(difference[j]!=difference[j+1]){
            missingTerm = arr[j]+difference[j+1];
            System.out.println("The missing term is: " + missingTerm );

        break;

}}}}
```

This program will help you find missing term of an AP.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this fail if the sequence is decreasing instead of increasing?
If I had the numbers 10, 8, 4, 2, 0, the missing value would be 6.
You find increment of -10/5 = -2 properly.
But then the loop you start from i = 10, decrease by 2... as long asi <= 0.  Well immediately i is > 0, so it'd exit the loop before decreasing at all.  < only works if increasing.
So it's the `i<=last` statement that I think is the problem.

So you'd need seem kind of way to adjust the `i<=last;` statement based upon whether it is a positive or negative increment.  I'm thinking it would have to do with absolute value and\or `Math.signum`, or including separate code section based upon a negative increment (not the fastest way, but reasonable).  But I've never done much in Java, and you asked for how it failed.  So hopefully there's your answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sort the array to ensure that this works for any case.
Arrays.sort(input_array)

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript based solution for the same:
This has 2 cases:

***CASE 1***:

- The array passed in has just one missing term, and the first and last
  terms are not the missing ones. It definitely has a missing term.
- In this case, we just need the array and use the basic school formula
- sum of n terms = `n/2 * (first + last)`

  ```
  function getMissingTerm(terms, n) {
      var expectedSum = ((terms.length + 1)/2) * (terms[0] + terms[terms.length - 1]),
          actualSum = 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < terms.length; ++i) {
          actualSum += parseInt(terms[i], 10);
      }

      return expectedSum - actualSum;

  }
  ```

---

***CASE 2***:

- The array passed does not have a missing term in itself
- meaning the missing term is either the first or last term
- In this case one must pass the length of the terms, n, which is greater than array length

  ```
  function getMissingTerm(terms, n) {
      var smallestDifference = Math.abs(terms[1] - terms[0]),
          missingTerm = null;

      for (var i = 2, diff; i < terms.length; ++i) {
          diff = Math.abs(terms[i] - terms[i - 1]);

          if (diff !== smallestDifference) {
              missingTerm = diff < smallestDifference ? i : i + 1;
          }
      }

      return (n && terms.length < n) ? 
          [terms[0] - smallestDifference, terms[n-2] + smallestDifference] : // return possible 2 terms, at the start and end of array
          terms[0] + (missingTerm - 1) * smallestDifference; // return the missing term
  }
  ```